# How do you detect if an html element can append child nodes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a custom jquery event called 'loading' in my application.  I want to append a masking element with a spinner, when this event is triggered.  I can figure out that part without problems.  However, some elements (images, form inputs, etc..) cannot append child elements.  I need to be able to detect if the target of this event can receive child elements. If it cannot, then I will add the spinner & mask to it's parent element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to check the name:

```
/*global $, jQuery */

function isVoid(el) {
    var tags = ['area', 'base', 'br', 'col', 'command', 'embed', 'hr', 'img', 'input',
                 'keygen', 'link', 'meta', 'param', 'source', 'track', 'wbr'],
        i = 0,
        l,
        name;

    if (el instanceof jQuery) {
        el = el[0];
    }

    name = el.nodeName.toLowerCase();

    for (i = 0, l = tags.length; i < l; i += 1) {
        if (tags[i] === name) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var el = document.getElementById('el'),
    elj = $('#el');

if (!isVoid(el)) {
    // append
}
```

Comment: indexOf isn't cross browser for arrays: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: Use _.indexOf if you support IE8 and older

Comment: Nice. May be worth adding `'#text'` just in case a text node finds its way in.

Comment: We don't support IE7 or below.  Doesn't indexOf work fine in IE8?

Comment: IE 9+ only, you can use a similar function http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-47

Comment: @NikPetersen This will work with IE7 and jQuery objects, since i now saw the jquery tag in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* add child elements, they just won't render.  This may sound like a semantic distinction, but it's critical to your problem: the DOM doesn't *know* whether a particular tag is rendered or not.

Your best bet is just to check manual:

```
var allowChildren = function(elem) {
   return ! (elem.nodeName in { INPUT : true, IMG : true }) ;
};
```

Comment: I have never seen that boolean syntax.  Is it valid?  So I suppose I could look up the spec for void elements, and add it to that hash.

Comment: I think creating a table of void elements will be the only real solution. Though I assume you mean `return !{ input : true, img : true }[elem.nodeName]`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/eGyRH/3/ -- Chrome lets me add a child element to an `<input>` tag, even though it's not displayed at all. It's visible in the DOM debugger, just not in the browser window.

Comment: @NikPetersen -- no, it was a typo.

Comment: @amnotiam -- it was a typo (now fixed), but "in" is better than a look up, as it does not *evaluate* the expression, just checks object-membership.

Comment: @Malvolio: Careful, the `!` has higher precedence than `in`. You're effectively doing `false in {input:true, img: true}`

Comment: ...also, check out [this jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/in-vs-lookup/2). It seems lookups are generally faster than `in`.

Comment: @amnotiam : It's 0.000000017 seconds faster on my machine.  You would have to execute it *57 million times* to save one second.  "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil." -- Donald Knuth

Comment: @Malvolio: *You're* the one who said `in` is better because it doesn't need to evaluate the expression. I could only assume you were talking about performance. If not performance, then why is does that make it better? Also, please fix your answer. It's still incorrect.

Comment: @amnotiam -- because I am trying to emulate a set, which is what `in` does.  The expression `!d[x]` means "is the key `x` unassigned in d, or if it is assigned, is it assigned a falsy value?" which is not what I mean.  (Fixed the code, thanks)

Comment: The code is not fixed. As I stated above, the `!` operator has a higher precedence than the `in` operator, so you're effectively doing `(!elem.nodeName) in {...}`. You need to associate the operands with the `in` so the `!` is applied to the result. You also need to use `.toLowerCase()`.

Comment: @amnotiam -- sorry, my edits didn't "take" for some reason.  I re-applied them.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/eGyRH/3/ -- Chrome lets me add a child element to an `<input>` tag, even though it's not displayed at all. It's visible in the DOM debugger, just not in the browser window.

However, I can test it's `.width()` and see that's equal to zero or not: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/eGyRH/4/

```
alert($('.element').append('<span>asdf</span>').children().width());​
```

However, this will also be zero width if, for instance, I'm adding the span to a hidden div: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/eGyRH/5/ -- so it's not totally reliable either.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer has a very nice fuction based on [which types of nodes can be void](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/syntax.html#void-elements).   It can be replaced by a jQuery one-liner:

`node.is("area,base,br,col,command,embed,hr,img,input,keygen,link,meta,param,source,track,wbr")`